# Hibernate 407 error when attempting to save object to database. (@OneToMany Relationship)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to set up a simple one to many relationship with two objects and attempting to follow some code I found here: https://github.com/hellokoding/jpa-onetomany-springboot-maven-mysql/blob/master/src/main/java/com/hellokoding/jpa/model/BookCategory.java#L29.

However, I'm getting issues when attempting to save an item to the specific database. I'm currently getting a 407 error based on my flt_id when attempting to save an object to my database.

Fleet object (I don't have any @OneToMany set just yet because I'm trying to simply save an object of this type to the database first before I attempt the @OneToMany stuff. Might this be the problem? Do I need to set up the entire thing, otherwise it breaks?)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "[name of fleet table]", schema = "[schema of fleet table]")
public class Fleet{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "FLT_ID")
    private int fltId;
    
    @Column(name = "FLT_NM")
    private String fleetName;
    
    @Column(name = "FLT_ASSN")
    private String fleetAssignment;
    
    //private List<FleetSerialNo> fleetSerialNo;
    
    public Fleet( ) {
        
    }

    public Fleet(String fleetName, String fleetAssignment) {
        super();
        this.fleetName = fleetName;
        this.fleetAssignment = fleetAssignment;

    }   
    
    
    public int getFltId() {
        return fltId;
    }
    
    public void setFltId(int fltId) {
        this.fltId = fltId;
    }

    /additional setters/getters
```

FleetSerialNo object I'd be connecting the @OneToMany to.

```
public class FleetSerialNo {

    @Column(name = "FLT_ID")
    private int fltId;
    
    @Column(name = "SER_NO_PFX")
    private String serialNoPrefix;
    
    @Column(name = "SER_NO_BDY")
    private String serialNoBody;
    
    private Fleet fleet;
    
    public FleetSerialNo() {
        
    }

    public FleetSerialNo(String serialNoPrefix, String serialNoBody, Fleet fleet) {
        super();
        this.serialNoPrefix = serialNoPrefix;
        this.serialNoBody = serialNoBody;
        this.fleet = fleet;
    }
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getFltId() {
        return fltId;
    }
    
    public void setFltId(int fltId) {
        this.fltId = fltId;
    }
```

StackTrace when attempting to save a fleet to the database

```
Hibernate: insert into [table name] (FLT_ID, CRTE_CUPID, CRTE_TS, FLT_ASSN, FLT_NM) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-07-01 08:01:22.823  WARN 22152 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: -407, SQLState: 23502
2020-07-01 08:01:22.829 ERROR 22152 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, SQLERRMC=FLT_ID, DRIVER=4.19.66
2020-07-01 08:01:22.934 ERROR 22152 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/rest/slt/fleet/save] due to exception [could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into [table name] (FLT_ID, CRTE_CUPID, CRTE_TS, FLT_ASSN, FLT_NM) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not prepare statement]

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into [table name] (FLT_ID, CRTE_CUPID, CRTE_TS, FLT_ASSN, FLT_NM) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:298) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.cat.pis.service.FleetServiceImpl.saveFleet(FleetServiceImpl.java:77) ~[classes/:1.0.2]
    at com.cat.pis.service.FleetServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f4731239.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:1.0.2]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.cat.pis.service.FleetServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4738f3bc.saveFleet(<generated>) ~[classes/:1.0.2]
    at com.cat.pis.endpoint.rest.SLTController.saveFleet(SLTController.java:136) ~[classes/:1.0.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:52) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:216) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.prepare(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3133) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3737) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:696) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:554) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 121 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, SQLERRMC=FLT_ID, DRIVER=4.19.66
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(kd.java:743) ~[db2jcc4-4.19.66.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(kd.java:66) ~[db2jcc4-4.19.66.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(kd.java:135) ~[db2jcc4-4.19.66.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fp.c(fp.java:2788) ~[db2jcc4-4.19.66.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fp.d(fp.java:2776) ~[db2jcc4-4.19.66.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fp.a(fp.java:2209) ~[db2jcc4-4.19.66.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gp.a(gp.java:7991) ~[db2jcc4-4.19.66.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fp.a(fp.java:2185) ~[db2jcc4-4.19.66.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.h(bb.java:136) ~[db2jcc4-4.19.66.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.b(bb.java:41) ~[db2jcc4-4.19.66.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.a(p.java:32) ~[db2jcc4-4.19.66.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.vb.i(vb.java:145) ~[db2jcc4-4.19.66.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fp.lb(fp.java:2178) ~[db2jcc4-4.19.66.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gp.Hc(gp.java:3868) ~[db2jcc4-4.19.66.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.findAutoGeneratedKeysColumn(Connection.java:6960) ~[db2jcc4-4.19.66.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:2716) ~[db2jcc4-4.19.66.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:323) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    ... 165 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
@Entity
public class Fleet{
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fleet", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<FleetSerialNo> fleetSerialNo;
...
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class FleetSerialNo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "FLT_ID")
    private int fltId;

    @ManyToOne
    private Fleet fleet;
 
    // @Id
    // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getFltId() {
        return fltId;
    }
...
}
```